# IBM i (System i) V7R1 upgrade causes cursor not open errors on ODBC connection

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

For years, at least 8, our company has been running a process daily that has never failed. Nothing on the client side has changed, but we recently upgraded to V7R1 on the System i. The very first run of the old process fails with a Cursor not open message reported back to the client, and that's all that's in the job log as well. I have seen Error -501, SQLSTATE 24501 on occasions.

I got both IBM and DataDirect (provider of the ODBC driver) involved. IBM stated it was a client issue, DataDirect dug through logs and found that when requesting the next block of records from a cursor this error occurs. They saw no indication that the System i alerted the client that the cursor was closed.

In troubleshooting, I noticed that the ODBC driver has an option for WITH HOLD which by default is checked. If I uncheck it, this particular issue goes away, but it introduces another issue (infinite loops) which is even more serious.

There's no single common theme that causes these errors, the only thing that I see that causes this is doing some processing while looping through a fairly large resultset. It doesn't seem to be related to timing, or to a particular table or table type. The outside loops are sometimes large tables with many datatypes, sometimes tiny tables with nothing but CHAR(10) and CHAR(8) data types.

I don't really expect an answer on here since this is a very esoteric situation, but there's always some hope.

There were other issues that IBM has already addressed by having us apply PTFs to take us to 36 for the database level. I am by no means a System i expert, just a Java programmer who has to deal with this issue that has nothing to do with Java at all.

Thanks

Comment: What was the prior version?  That's important because of changes IBM made to SQL between 5.4 and 7.1 in order to tighten up error reporting.  To help you troubleshoot, try the same SQL statements directly on IBM i - get on a green screen and use STRSQL to run the failing SQL statements.

Comment: @BuckCalabro We went from V6R1 to V7R1, the problem is it's not a statement that is failing. The statement works, it's just that when the ODBC driver requests the next block of results the i just reports the cursor is closed. Removing or rearranging the code the client performs changes the point at which the error occurs, sometimes eliminating it entirely, but the processing is what's needed.

Comment: @BuckCalabro And to be clear, this isn't related to a single query or a single table or a single data type, this is an intermittent weird failure that occurs when processing large resultsets. I have no clear definition of large, but large enough that the ODBC driver makes multiple requests for blocks of results. The error occurs at a request for more results.

Comment: The point of running on a different platform is to inspect the returned rows to make sure that DB2 isn't now returning a warning where it never used to.  If it turns out that the first block of results doesn't have any dodgy columns (luck of the ORDER BY draw) then the first block comes back as expected.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaq9/rzaq9.pdf  Page 23.

Comment: @BuckCalabro I thought of that already, as this type of thing has caused issues with the ODBC driver in the past. The table in question where the issue occurred is devoid of anything that may cause an error, CHAR fields, all nullable, no constraints, etc. There are no warnings in the ODBC trace DataDirect did, and IBM confirmed the issue is as DataDirect reports from a TRCCNN: they just need more info to debug it, and I'm having trouble gathering it. I can run the entire query in Squirrel using the JT400 JDBC driver and get back all results without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Have you tried it with IBM's ODBC driver?  Or since it's Java, why aren't you using JDBC?

Comment: @Charles The Client Access driver doesn't support all the operations necessary, and it's not Java, the client is actually OpenEdge (Progress) using their DataServer product for DB2.

Comment: @BuckCalabro Thanks for that memo, about half way down page 27 is an interesting paragraph on Host Server DRDA connection cursor attributes. It at least gives me something to search on.

Comment: That is interesting, particularly the part about *"In prior releases, the default cursor attributes for sensitivity, scrolling, holding and updating were used for many cursors."*  Especially since you mention that unchecking `WITH HOLD` makes the problem go away.  Although to be honest, I'd expect it to work opposite.    Is there anything else going on between fetches of blocks of records?

Comment: @Charles There is a lot going on, some other fetches, a few updates to tables, some client side processing (writing logs, sending emails). If I remove 100% of the client processing everything works just fine. In another instance of this same issue (different tables, different catalog even), if we ADD client processing (scaffolding) the problem goes away. It's truly a weird issue.

Comment: I know this is for z/OS, but it sounds suspiciously like what I'm seeing http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_optimize4smallsets4drda.dita

Comment: One more little detail. This issue seems to be sporadic, however, once it's produced if you execute the same query over and over it fails at exactly the same spot. Make a minor change to the where clause or in some cases the length of time spent between requests for blocks of data and the error occurs elsewhere (or not at all).

Comment: It turns that IBM had made changes to how 3 part naming is handled somewhere between V6R1 and V7R1. They are working on a PTF to undo some of those changes. Once I have it in my hands and test it I'll give the details in case someone else comes across this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for anyone else out there who may run across a similar issue. It turns out it was a bug in the QRWTSRVR code that caused the issue. The driver opened up several connections within a single job and used the same name for cursors in at least 2 of those connections. Once one of those cursors was closed QRWTSRVR would mistakenly attempt to use the closed cursor and return the error. Here is the description from the PTF cover letter:

### DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM FIXED FOR APAR SE62670 :

```
    A QRWTSRVR job with 2 cursors named C01 takes a MSGSQL0501
error when trying to fetch from the one that is open. The DB2
code is trying to use the cursor which is pseudo closed.
```

The PTF SI57756 fixed the issue. I do not know that this PTF will be generally released, but if you find this post because of a similar issue hopefully this will assist you in getting it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fix DB problems on the iseries.

Start journaling the tables on the iseries or change the connection to the iseries to commit = *NONE.

for the journaling I recommend using two journals each with its own receiver.

one journal for tables with relatively few changes like a table of US States or a table that gets less than 10 updates a month.  This is so you can determine when the data was changed for an audit.  Keep all the receivers for this journal on-line for ever.

one journal for tables with many changes through out the day.  Delete the receivers for these journals when you can no longer afford the space they take up.

If the journal or commit *none doesn't fix it.  You'll need to look at the sysixadv table long running queries can wreck an ODBC connection.

SELECT SYS_TNAME, TBMEMBER, INDEX_TYPE, LASTADV, TIMESADV, ESTTIME,
REASON, "PAGESIZE", QUERYCOST, QUERYEST, TABLE_SIZE, NLSSNAME,
NLSSDBNAME, MTIUSED, MTICREATED, LASTMTIUSE, QRYMICRO, EVIVALS,
FIRSTADV, SYS_DNAME, MTISTATS, LASTMTISTA, DEPCNT FROM sysixadv
ORDER BY ESTTIME desc

also order by timesadv desc

fix those queries maybe create the advised index.

Comment: All table are journaled. I don't see how this addresses the question at all. The question was in regard to a process that worked for years and suddenly stopped after an upgrade to the System i OS.

Comment: Well after an upgrade there is a manditory IPL that will erase all the system created indexes MTI which will cause query to run slow lost connections etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but the table is really simple, no indexes advised. This client program has run unchanged for many years without issue. I believe something was done to the query optimizer that is now aggressively closing cursors when it believes they are "abandoned."

Answer (score 0):

Which ODBC driver are you using?

If you're using the IBM i Access ODBC driver, then this problem may be fixed by APAR [SE61342](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas236851854e54befdc86257df00041ecfe). The driver didn't always handle the return code from the server that indicated that the result set was closed and during the SQLCloseCursor function, the driver would send a close command to the server, which would return an error, since the server had already closed the cursor. Note, you don't have to be at SP11 to hit this condition, it just made it easier to hit, since I enabled pre-fetch in more cases in that fixpack. An easy test to see if that is the problem is to disable pre-fetch for the DSN or pass PREFETCH=0 on the connection string.

If you're using the DB2 Connect driver, I can't really offer much help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm using a third party driver. The answer to the question was to get IBM development involved and have them create a PTF for me. Check my answer below for more details.